# Linking to libvorbis nad libvorbisfile failed - LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__floor

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2017, static-linking

I use VS 2017. I have added linking to `libvorbis_static.lib` and `libvorbisfile_static.lib` for an exisiting project. During linking I get a few errors with the same message:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__floor
```

Paths and library names are correct. When I create a new VS 2017 project with the default settings linking works fine so the above errors are generated due to exisitng project settings or defines. How to fix that ?

Comment: `__imp` means it's expecting you to link to an import library for a dll. I would not expect that to be a file named `*_static.lib`

Comment: @drescherjm When I link to dynamic versions of libvorbis libraries everything works fine but I don't understand why a dynamic library force me to link to a dynamic version of the libvorbis libraries.

Comment: There is probably some macro that controls  the switch between dynamic and static linking. A second reason for the error could be that you compiled for dynamic linking to these libraries then switched to static libraries without a totally clean build (may have to manually delete the precompiled headers file if it exists).  Or it could be a bug in the libraries you link which makes static linking not work on msvc.

Comment: Personally, when building / linking in VS, I use entirely static libraries (`/MT` / `/MTd`).  This avoids the issue entirely and also means that you don't have to worry about (the correct version of) the runtime library DLLs being present on the target machine (or bundled as part of your installer package).

Comment: Where did you obtain or build the libraries you are using? Note that in general C++ static libraries are NOT compatible between versions of Visual C++. This has been a feature of VS 2015 Update 3 - VS 2022 for 'forward' compatibility only. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017).

Comment: Using the static version of the Visual CRT is NOT recommended, which is why most scenarios default to using the dynamic Visual CRT version.

Comment: Note the best option is to use the [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html) manager, have it build libvorbis for you, and use the triplet that matches you desired build settings (dll, static lib+static CRT, or static lib+DLL CRT).

Comment: Can you provide the source link of the library and a minimal sample code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Have you checked the header file of the library for the #pragma statement?